# Using open source code/software in web apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, licensing

I'm having some trouble recently with the open source licenses. I started to feel like if they are somehow tricky! So, I'm just asking about the rights, attribution and so on..

Know, if I for example used a Ruby Gem, licensed under GPL, I install the gem, use it, my web app works! But there is no referring to the Gem, how is behind it, its license. I can't just believe that I have to include those for every gem I'm using. Do I have to? Or can I just use it *silently*?

So, a website with Rails (MIT), some GPL ruby gems, and so on, what should I include publicly? I think I'm not going to modify the source code of any of those gems.. Yeah, and if I have to attribute in my web pages, do I have to link to the licenses or even worse distribute my source code under the same license?

Also, if I found a tutorial or something like that that is licensed under Creative Commons BY-NC, should I distribute my whole work or put it under the same license, if I wasn't going to run them outside my own server? What if I wanted to distribute my software, which used ideas (and modified code) from the tutorial?

What about using formulas, which are more general than being owned? One-liner commands from stackoverflow when a gem doesn't install - Should I attribute that I used that to install the gem?! I think of course not, but just asking to make sure of the whole thing..

Comment: This is not a programming question but a legal question. You should ask this on a legal forum, or even better yet, you should ask your lawyer.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Well, may be. But it is a kind of.. about software. I mean I thought many developers here have worked more than once with open source software and know what to do.

Comment: Have you *looked* at the quality of answers about legal questions on this site? If you have a programming question, ask a programmer. If you have a gardening question, ask a gardener. If you have a legal question, ask a lawyer. It's simply a question of risk mitigation: if someone gives you a wrong programming answer on StackOverflow, you'll notice it when you try to compile it. If someone gives you a wrong legal answer on StackOverflow, you'll notice it when you get sued for everything you own. Lawyers are liable for giving wrong legal advice, random anonymous strangers on the net aren't.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looks like I have to look some where else, may be just go and retry searching!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A website is normally the output of a program. Like you save a text-document with your word processor in disk, the document itself does not fall under the reciprocal license of the proprietary word processor (MS Word) or the reciprocal and permissive licenses of the free software word processor (Open or Libre Office Writer).

Only in case you create and distribute derivative or combined works (e.g. packaging multiple programs together in one package) you need to care about the licenses.

That for sure always depends on the concrete things you do. You need to document these concrete things, then go to your lawyer and then find out for the stuff you exactly do if and how copyright is in effect and based on the licenses used and if in effect, which steps you need to do.

Here on SO we are all only software developers (or if lawyers, not *your* lawyer) so we can not give you any legal support.

Comment: [This FAQ item reinforces the idea that you could use a GPL library (and even modifying it) in the serving or creation of a web site](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#UnreleasedMods).  As long as you do not redistribute your software, it should not alter your source license and if you modified the GPL library you aren't forced to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually stuff about licences can be a little confusing with open source software being released under different licences and usually the license documentation is usually written in lawyer jargon which proves difficult to understand for a lot of people.

Luckily this kind of question has been asked alot of times in SO. Just look at the licensing tag and order the questions by votes and you should find a few questions that pretty much answer your questions. In particular look at this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94346/can-i-legally-incorporate-gpl-lgpl-open-sourced-software-in-a-proprietary-cl)